# $S, T$ be multiplicatively closed sets in the ring $R$, such that $S \subseteq T$ Show that the following are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $S, T$ be multiplicatively closed sets in the ring $R$, such that $S\subseteq T$.

Let $\varphi : S^{−1}R \to T^{−1}R$ be the homomorphism which maps each $r/s \in S^{−1}R$ to $r/s$ viewed as an element of $T^{−1}R$. Show that the following are equivalent:

> (i) $\varphi$ is a bijection;
>
> (ii) $t/1$ is a unit in $S^{−1}R$ for all $t\in T$;
>
> (iii) for all $t\in T$ there exists $r\in R$ such that $rt\in S$;
>
> (iv) every prime ideal of $R$ which meets $T$ also meets $S$.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I have deleted all the wrong tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: The equivalence of (i) and (ii) is an easy consequence of the universal property of localizations. The equivalence of (ii) and (iii) follows from the usual explicit description of $S^{-1} R$. The equivalence of (ii) and (iv) follows from the characterization of prime ideals in localizations.

I hope that - this time - no complete solution is posted here, so that this exercise will remain an exercise.